# Blazor refresh List of Child Component

Tags: c#, blazor

Consider the following Blazor `ParentComponent` that renders a list of `ChildComponent`s:

```
<input type="date" @bind-Value="date" />
<button type="button" @onclick="ChangeDate"> Filter </button>

foreach(var i in list)
{
   <ChildComponent Id="i.Id" Date="date" />
}

@code{
   List<int> list; //a list of ids for this example
   DateTime date = DateTime.Today; //date ChildComponent should be filtered by
   
   async Task ChangeDate()
   {
      //What do I write here to call StateHasChanged() on ChildComponents?
   }
}
```

How would I call `StateHasChanged()` on all `ChildComponent`'s from `ParentComponent`?

Comment: Can you explain in detail on what condition you want Child Component to render again? Not sure if what you have shared is sufficient enough to provide you a solution. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal done, btw SO wasn't happy with that edit because "it looks like your question is mostly code" 

Comment: Why do you have to call ```StateHasChanged``` for the child components?  If you change the parameter like ```Id``` in your example, this will trigger a render cycle for the child component.  If you call  ```StateHasChanged``` on the parent, this triggers the process for all the children too. So maybe you can elaborate on what you try to achieve and what part is not working.

Comment: @Justthebenno my `ChildComponent` has a list filtered based on date, when date changes I have to refetch that list from a service. `StateHasChanged` is probably the wrong function to call, I'll add an answer later of what worked.

Comment: Have you tried to override ```OnParametersSetAsync``` or ```OnParametersSetAsync``` on the child component? This method is invoked as soon as any parameter has changed.

Answer (score 1):

In general this is the job of a Service.  Your data lives in (lets call it) DateService.  DateService contains a list of items with IDs and Dates.  When you change the date (in any or all the list items) as you do here in the "Page" component, you trigger a ListHasChanged event/delegate that you have set up in the service. Each `ChildComponent` uses Dependency Injection to get the service and registers an internal event handler to the event in `OnInitializedAsync`.  The event handler re-renders if necessary. Note: Always call `StateHasChanged` with Invoke - you can never guarantee which thread is calling it with event handlers.  I've shown a generic event handler which re-renders a component.

```
protected async void RenderAsync(object sender, EventArgs e) => await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
```

I'll post some more detailed code if requested.

[MS detail on Services and DI here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly)